# How do I fill this very challenging table?

Tags: puzzle

I am practicing for a very hard logic competition in Lebanon and I was asked two questions.

1. Complete the following table:

[image]

2. Who am I?

Can anyone give me a hint? I really have no idea how to start! I tried to fill in blanks by using the sum, like 0+0.01 = 0.01, then 1.99 + 0.01 = 2 and etc...

I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to know what's going on from just this, but assuming that the first table is supposed to mean "find two numbers whose sum is given in the right-hand column" and the second table is supposed to mean "find two numbers whose difference is given in the right-hand column" AND the two tables are expecting the same two values for each row (and this is a *lot* of assumptions...) you have simple simultaneous equations.

The first row becomes:
$$ a + b = 230 \quad \mbox{and} \quad a - b = 50 $$
for which the solutions are $a=140$ and $b=90$ (add the two equations to get $2a = 280$, solve for $a$ and substitute back into either equation to solve for $b$).

The last row becomes:
$$ a + b = 0.01 \quad \mbox{and} \quad a - b = 0 $$
for which the solutions are $a = 0.005$ and $b=0.005$.

Everything in between you should be able to complete now.